# Terraform for google firebase vs. firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, terraform-provider-gcp

For setting up Firebase in a Google Cloud Project, the Google terraform provider provides two resources:
**google_firebase_project**
**google_firebase_project_location**

My understanding is that Firestore is a component of Firebase, so setting the location of the Firebase project also sets the location of the Firestore database.

However, the google Firestore documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/automate-database-create#create_a_database_with_terraform) says to use **google_app_engine_application** to configure the Firestore location (and type).

Is it possible to configure Firestore *without* Firebase?
Is it possible to configure Firebase *without* Firestore?
Is it possible to configure different locations for Firestore and Firebase in the same GCP?
If I create Firestore using:

```
resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = google_project.my_project.project_id
  location_id = "location"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```

do I still need to create the *google_firebase_project* and/or *google_firebase_project_location* resources? Can I create them? Should I create them? Can I get away with NOT creating them?

At the end of the day, what I want is a Google Cloud Project with Firestore in Native mode and a particular location. I tried using **google_firebase_project_location**, but this created Firestore in the desired location but NOT in Native mode. I now have to create another GCP project and would like to ensure the Firestore is in Native mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be helped by reading this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations).

> Is it possible to configure Firestore without Firebase?

Yes.  [Firestore is a Google Cloud product](https://cloud.google.com/firestore), and Firebase adds APIs and functionality to it relevant for web and mobile apps.  [Read this](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e).  It works just fine without anything related to Firebase.

> Is it possible to configure Firebase without Firestore?

Yes.  You are free to use Firebase without touching Firestore at all.

> Is it possible to configure different locations for Firestore and Firebase in the same GCP?

No.  Refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) I linked at the top.  Firestore always uses your default project location, which you are forced to select before you use a cloud product that requires a location.  Not all products require a location, but once you choose one for a project, it's locked in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Doug Stevenson.  If I create a google_firebase_project, I get an Admin SDK service account created. Will this same service account be created if I enable Firestore only, using google_app_engine_application, without google_firebase_project?

Comment: I don't know.  That sounds like a new question to post specifically about how terraform works with Google Cloud.  Or, even better, try it yourself?

Comment: I'd like to try it myself. Problem is project creation is controlled in my org - I can't create/drop projects at will.  I believe this post is specifically about Terraform and Google, though I appreciate the info you provided about Google products.

Comment: Almost everything you've asked about here has nothing to do with Terraform.  I was able to answer them without any knowledge of that. I'd strongly suggest posting a new question to drill into the specific thing about terraform you want to know.  It also helps tp limit your post to a single question, which will increase your chances of getting it answered (and help others in the future with the same question).  Single question per post is technically a requirement on SO, else your question may be closed by the community.